# C++ on Ubuntu Linux: How to block every standard hotkey

Tags: ubuntu

How can I have the OS ignore every hotkey known to it? What I want is to run a graphical program on top of it (as shell or not) and have zero possibility of getting out of it.

Comment: @cHao: +1 if you write me a script that does this for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681786/linux-help-for-translation-of-windows-program-in-linux/8681856#8681856

Comment: @Eugen: Actually I'm not sure whether this could totally crash a Linux system.

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark that's the sweet point: It would still run the graphical program on top of it and have zero possibility of getting out of it.

Comment: @Eugen: whoops, I was reading "HDDs" in your comment... It's getting late. Good point, although this is also hard to do programatically.

Comment: Well, if you are root, you could unload ps2 and usb drivers if compiled as a module. Alternativly you could misconfigure the Xserver as much as to make the HIDs fail

Comment: @Eugen: `SysRq` combos will still work, even if the Xserver is completely crippled. But your idea of unloading the HID kernel modules is creative and refreshingly evil at the same time.